# FCM WEB receive only data and hide notification section or Disable

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send data form my server to FCM, so that it can be shown on a specific section of my web page. It's like a stock application for example, where the data is constantly updated. In the same way am trying to achieve. So far I have configured it to receive data from FCM and it is being received. But the problem is that it shows the notification to like. My colleague are working on the same there is a option to send only data to the android app and hide notifications to be shown. Likewise I want to do it hear on web, but am unable to do it.

```
(function () {
    // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
        apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        authDomain: "test-xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.com",
        databaseURL: "https://xxxxxx-xxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "xxx-469e9",
        storageBucket: "",
        messagingSenderId: "xxxxxx"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    // Retrieve Firebase Messaging object.
    const messaging = firebase.messaging();
    messaging.requestPermission()
    .then(function() {
        console.log('Notification permission granted.');
        return messaging.getToken();
    })

    .then(function(token) {
        console.log(token);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
    })

    messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
        console.log("Message received. ", payload);
        // ...
    });

}());
```

on firebase-messaging-sw.js

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.1/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.1/firebase-messaging.js');
// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx.com",
    databaseURL: "https://xxx-xxx.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

Comment: i'm trying to understand your question. You want to send some data but without the notification popping up?

Comment: thanks for the reply yes exactly, coz the problem is like i will be sending data every 4 or 5 second if user gets background notifications it will be disturbing 
1. option is hide notification popup
2. if possible disable notification when window is closed and re enable on open or ask

Comment: the firebase provides with it's realtime database the ability to passively listen to the changes to the data, and react. If the data that you update is (nested) in one node, then you maybe don't need the messaging to send the data?

Comment: but real time data base is paid option and hear it is a free and like in android we are using so checking for the web same

Answer (score 1):

A hack would be to close the notification just after...

```
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
    var realPush = true;

    if(realPush)
    {
        const notificationOptions = {
            body: "It is a REAL push",
            data:"true"
        };

        //We display the notification
        return  self.registration.showNotification(title, notificationOptions);
    }else
    {
        const notificationOptions = {
            body: "It is a SILENT push",
            data:"false"
        };

        //We display a fake notification
        return self.registration.showNotification('To delete',notificationOptions).then(function () {
            self.registration.getNotifications().then(notifications => {
                console.log(notifications);
                for (var i =0;i<notifications.length;i++)
                {
                    if(notifications[i].data != "true")
                    {
                        //then we destroy the fake notification immedialtely !
                        notifications[i].close();
                    }
                }
            })
        });

    }

});
```

The realPush parameter is of course managed by yourself